# How do i arrange multiple counters from high to low and showing the counter name tag aswell (which is a char)?

Tags: c

I've been studying C programming for the past 3 weeks in my college, and this is my first ever homework, I have managed to finish 95% of it on my own but i got to this part where i am stuck!
so what the question asks is that you enter 4 diff chars to the progam ( "N"  , "R", "F", "T") and what i have to do is count everytime a char shows up and then display the number of times each char showed up and arrange them in a descending order, like this:

[image]

I got everything sorted and all i have left is to link the correct char to the highest counter ,Now I can do this with a whole lot of IF's but I don't think its a good way to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


printf("Enter answers (R-radio, T-tv, N-newspaper, F-facebook, * to finish\n");
ch = getch();
putch(ch);
while (ch != '*') {
    switch (ch) {

    case 'R':
        rc++;

        break;
    case 'T':
        tc++;

        break;
    case 'F':
        fc++;
        break;
    case 'N':
        nc++;

        break;

    default:
        if (error == 0) {
            temp1 = ch;
            error = 1;
        }
        break;


    }
    ch = getch();
    putch(ch);

}
a = rc;
b = nc;
c = tc;
d = fc;

int i;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    if (d > c) {
        temp = c;
        c = d;
        d = temp;
    }
    if (c > b) {
        temp = b;
        b = c;
        c = temp;
    }
    if (b > a) {
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;

    }

}

if (error == 1) {
    printf("\nIllegal input : %c\n", temp1);
}
else {
    printf("\n1. %c (%d)",a, a);
    printf("\n2. R (%d)", b);

    printf("\n3. F (%d)", c);

    printf("\n4. T (%d)", d);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you feel like showing what you have done?

Comment: You want to put the char and its count in a structure and then sort the structure based on count.

Comment: I am not quite sure if I know what you mean, didn't teach us that in the course yet... can u explain ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think another solution is to populate an string array[2] for each letter, one element will be for the letter and another will be for the counter. You can use the second element for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need some "container" for storing paired values- let me say eg. `key` and `value`- according to the `Map`, or `Hashmap` from the another languages.

In C language you are possible to make your own "objects", it is called `structures`. That is probably the best way.

Another way can be eg. to make some "pseudo-csv" - string array in format `[key;value]`, but you have to split it and parse value as a number anytime. *So that solution is a little messy, let me say.*

Not so effective, but also satisfying solution can be to make your own function for obtain max from an array of the numbers (values of each answers), and after that to compare it with the variables value- like bellow:

- 1st iteration:

  - pass array `[rc,nc,tc,fc]` (eg. 10,15,5,3)
  - obtain 15, compare to each variable rc,nc,tc,fc- 15 is nc
  - print `15 (N)`
- 2nd iteration

  - pass array `[rc,tc,fc]` (eg. 10,5,3)
  - obtain 10, compare to each variable rc,tc,fc, it is rc
  - print `10 (C)`

etc..

> But there you have also the problem if count of some options will be the same